# Proving that if $S$ has an infinite subset then $S$ is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> **Definition**$\quad$ A set $S$ can be defined as *infinite* if there exists a mapping from $S$ to $S$ that is one-to-one but not onto. Otherwise, $S$ is *finite*.

**Problem:** Using the definition of infinite above, prove that if a set $S$ has an infinite subset, then $S$ is infinite.

**My attempt:** Suppose $T\subseteq S$, where $T$ is infinite. By the supplied definition of infinite, there exists a mapping $\eta\colon T\to T$ that is one-to-one but not onto. That is, for all $x_1,x_2\in T$, we have $\eta(x_1)=\eta(x_2)\to x_1=x_2$, but there exists $\tau\in T$ such that $\eta(x)\neq\tau$ for all $x\in T$.

Consider a one-to-one and onto mapping $\delta\colon S\setminus T\to S\setminus T$. There exists a mapping $\gamma\colon S\to S$ such that
$$
\gamma\colon S\to S\equiv
\begin{cases}
\eta\colon T\to T &\text{if $x\in T$},\\[0.25em]
\delta\colon S\setminus T\to S\setminus T &\text{if $x\in S\setminus T$}. 
\end{cases}
$$
The mapping $\gamma\colon S\to S$ is one-to-one because $x_1,x_2\in T\cup S\setminus T\to x_1,x_2\in S$ and $\gamma(x_1)=\gamma(x_2)\to x_1=x_2$ because $\eta$ and $\delta$ are both one-to-one mappings. However, $\gamma$ is not onto because there exists an element in $S$, namely $\tau$ (since $\tau\in T\to\tau\in S$ because $T\subseteq S$), that is not mapped to. Hence, there exists a mapping $\gamma$ from $S$ to $S$ that is one-to-one but not onto when $T\subseteq S$ and $T$ is infinite. Thus, $S$ is infinite. $\Box$

**Question:** Is this a good/correct proof? If not, where did I go wrong? If it is correct, then is there a way I can improve it or is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: Looks good to me. The only thing I would change is to use the identity on $S\setminus T$ as $\delta$.

Comment: I find it perfect.

Comment: @A.P. I'm not sure what you mean exactly. What do you mean by "use the identity"?

Comment: I mean the map $x \mapsto x$.

Comment: @A.P. Ah, I think I see what you mean: $(\forall x\in S\setminus T)(x\mapsto x)$...defining $\delta$ in that way right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ^_^

Comment: @ajotatxe Thanks for the vote of confidence and support :)

Comment: @A.P. Thanks for the input! That does it make it simpler since the identity mapping is always onto and one-to-one...I can make it more specific in that sense. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me. The only thing I would change is to define $\delta$ as the identity on $S∖T$, i.e. as
$$
\begin{align}
\delta \colon S \setminus T &\to S \setminus T \\
x &\mapsto x
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'm not looking for easy rep, but if you accept this (or any other) answer your question will not appear unanswered anymore, contributing to keep the site a bit more tidy.

Comment: Could always make it CW

Comment: @MagicMan I'm a bit ashamed about this, but I couldn't find the option. :P